# Authentication call shows password in dev tools

Tags: node.js, authentication, encryption, ldap

Authentication call is a http post call, passing in username and password in the request body.

The problem is that the username and password show when you use dev tools (F12) on Chrome browser.

What is the easiest way to fix this? This is a node application using ldap for authentication.

```
var client = ldap.createClient(domain);
var result = await client.authenticate(request.user, request.password);
```

Comment: Not sure of the question, your talking about the username and password being shown client side, when posting to your node app?

Comment: Yes. Once user enters the username and password and clicks submit button, the authentication call is fired. When check the dev tools, the request payload is displayed with the password. This is a security issue. I would like to encode the password but not sure how to do it.